# Highlighting search results in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have just downloaded Notepad++ as I use it to work with large data. I usually search for lines missing data so I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for *,,* as that means my data is missing. After it gives me the results I try to highlight them by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> but it seems it copies the original text instead. I know people did <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to do it but this does not work on mine.

Any advice?

Answer (score 16):

Notepad++ does this by either marking or bookmarking the lines.

Example file;

[image: Example file]

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and click the *Mark* tab. Enter the *,,* search criteria, click *Bookmark line* checkbox, then finally the *Mark All* button.

[image: Mark lines]

Now with the lines Bookmarked, from the drop down menu click Search --> Bookmark, and there's a multitude of options; whether you want to copy them out to another file, remove them altogether, etc.

[image: Bookmark options]

As a final note, make sure your Notepad++ is up to date, as features have been added since you asked this question. The current version as of writing is v6.6.3